# $P^2$ vs projection plane

Tags: 3d, projections, 2d, affine-transformations

I want to explain what I understood of definition of the two things.

**Projection plane:**
The general processing steps for modeling and converting a world coordinate description of a scene to
device coordinates, we need projection plane.

**Projective plane:** We know that $P^2$ is all $\mathbb R^2$ points and point at infinity.In projection plane any point exists in $(∞,∞)$ if we want to represents it then we need projective plane.

For instance, a point in Cartesian $(1, 2)$ becomes $(1, 2, 1)$ in Homogeneous. If a point, $(1, 2)$, moves toward infinity, it becomes $(∞,∞)$ in Cartesian coordinates. And it becomes $(1, 2, 0)$ in Homogeneous coordinates, because of $(1/0, 2/0) ≈ (∞,∞).$ Notice that we can express the point at infinity without using $"∞".$

My question is what's difference between Projection plane and Projective plane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In computer graphics the projection plane is most commonly defined as a plane perpendicular to the camera at a specific distance from the camera (the distance is often labeled $g$). It is the plane that an image will be projected onto and is usually shown between the near and far planes of a projection matrix. In the attached image (from the fged website) it is the blue plane.
[image: Projection plane example]

The projective plane on the other hand is usually shown as being parallel with the camera (or nearly parallel) extending out to infinity and typically has two lines draw on it like railroad tracks that meet (at infinity). Projective planes are not generally computed, though sometimes the need comes up. While a "projection plane" is mostly just conceptual, real world examples of a "projective plane" can be found. I attached a couple images showing some examples.
[image]
[image]

There are other definitions of projective plane (such as the one over at wolfram math) but from my experience these are the two most common definitions and what folks generally are referring to when using the terms.

Comment: in the first image I can capture image by camera is green plane blue plane?

Comment: The first image is an example projection, the green plane is the near plane, the gray plane is the far plane and the camera would be positioned at $o$ which is the origin.

Comment: But which plane's image camera got captured, it is blue plane?

Comment: Yes, the blue plane.

Comment: "Projective planes are not generally computed" - don't understand this line... Please elaborate little bit.

Comment: In most CG techniques there is no need to actually compute a projective plane, it is more conceptual like the railroad tracks merging in the distance.

Comment: But in answer you wrote "projection plane" is conceptual?

Comment: Well they are both general concepts I was trying to convey that in CG the projective plane is more of a conceptual teaching aid and not used much beyond that.

Comment: OK.. Everything understood... But one thing confusing me. In projective plane is parallel to camera means it is perpendicular also. And projection plane is perpendicular to camera means it is parallel also. Am I correct?

Comment: No, a Projection plane is always perpendicular as shown in the image and a projective plane is always parallel (or almost  parallel) to the camera. It is a bit confusing because they are both planes, but each is serving a specific purpose.

Comment: if I catch the image of railway track by projection plane then it will look like similar of projective plane image?